# Suspicious series of downvotes

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Yesterday I became a victim of several (uncommented) downvotes which can't be related to some serious quality issues (for example all questions I asked so far have been downvoted). So I suspect this was happening for personal reasons only, and I think I know which user this may be (but i will not make this public). My question is now how to deal with that. It is clear that I never will get any response if I just ask about the downvotes in the comment section of the questions/answer in question. Ignore? And is there a mechanism to undo this obviously unjustified loss of reputation?
In case there exists already a topic like this, my deepest apologies I wasn't able to hunt it down!

Comment: Already passed to the team. I'm a bit surprised that the script wasn't triggered, but well. Expect an invalidation in the not-too-distant future.

Comment: I'd be mildly curious whom you suspect (**don't** name). Usually, people's suspicions are remarkably unreliable in these matters.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for the prompt response!! :)

Comment: @DanielFischer i got a total of 5 downvotes (totally unjustified in my opinion) on a specific question the last days. My question is, will this be detected by the system and hopefully removed? i suspect some revenege downvotes here...

Comment: If the votes are on the same post, they come from different users, and that is not serial voting. The system only looks at votes from a single user.

Comment: @DanielFischer first of all, thanks for the prompt response (again)! Does this mean that we can do nothing about it?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is anything to do about it. People can judge your post differently from you. If they downvoted because they considered your answer not helpful, that's legitimate, whether anybody else agrees with the assessment or not. I don't see anything that indicates foul play.

Comment: I have also got a downvote on an obviously correct question.It is hard for me to understand the reasons behind this.